# Finding disk space details Linux server

Tags: linux, diskspace, du, linux-disk-free

I have a strange issue.
When I use the below command

```
[user@lautpyy003d ~]$ df -h /app/dev-data Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on nfspci1q-2421-03.xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx:/app_nfs/lautpyy003d_4d_app_dev-data 68G 55G 14G 81% /app/dev-data
```

The above tells me that out of 68G, 55G is used.

However, when I fetch a detailed report, I see the below

```
[user@lautpyy003d /app/dev-data]$ du -sh * | sort -hr | head -n20
5.9G    node1
2.9G    node2
64M     memberareas
52M     output
4.4M    data_purge_jobs
104K    input
96K     wlstemplates
```

It just shows me a total of around 10G, doesn't show me the rest 45G. Any idea where I am going wrong. Where are these 45G data located?

Comment: Try to use `du -h your_directory`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`df` shows you the free space of the volume. Most likely, `/app_nfs/lautpyy003d_4d_app_dev-data` is not the root folder on that filesystem on the server.